# Jquery – Count characters on single line in contentEditable DIV

Tags: jquery, charactercount

Is it possible at all to count the number of characters for a single line. Let's say that we have a paragraph of 5 lines, is it possible to count the number of characters of each line.
Everything I was able to find so far counts the number of characters for the entire paragraph...

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
var lines = $("yourDiv").text().split("\n");
$.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
            console.log(elem.length);
          });
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the console returns the number of characters of the entire text. My text is a paragraph within a contentEditble div. _Edit_ What I mean is that the lines break because of the width of the container div, there is no "physical" line break. I guess what I'm asking for is impossible to achieve.

Comment: i think you can estimate the  length at wich the line breaks implicitely , and split your div according to each line length.